# Google Sheets Pie Chart - Display Actual Value Below Label, not in pie chart?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I know I can get the actual value to show up in the pie chart, i.e. on the slice. However I want the percentage in the pie chart (which I can get to show up) since it is more likely to fit in a slice and the actual value underneath the label. However no matter what I do I can't get anything besides the respective percentage to show up underneath each slice's label. Help!

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I understand that you want to change your pie graph hiding the percentage shown inside the pie slice. If that is your goal, then you only have to update one chart setting. Follow these steps:

1. Double left click on the chart. The chart editor sidebar will open.
2. Click on the `Customise` tab.
3. Open the `Pie chart` submenu.
4. Update the `Slice label` property from `Percentage` to `None`.

Comment: Thanks but look at the picture again. I drew arrows to where I want the actual value, not a percentage, to be. I know how to change the display on the actual pie slice like you described.